# How to send props by clicking image in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm using [Dialog](https://material-ui.com/demos/dialogs/) component in `Material-UI`.

I set up onClick so that I can open the dialog when clicking the image.

```js
<img
  onClick={this.handleClickOpen}
  alt="..."
  src={studio2}
  className={navImageClasses}
/>
```

This is how the dialog looks in the code level

```js
<Dialog
  open={this.state.open}
  TransitionComponent={Transition}
  keepMounted
  onClose={this.handleClose}
>
  <DialogTitle id="alert-dialog-slide-title">
    {"Test title"}
  </DialogTitle>
  <DialogContent>
    <DialogContentText id="alert-dialog-slide-description">
      {"I wanna put the image here."}
    </DialogContentText>
  </DialogContent>
</Dialog>
```

When I click the image, I wanna pass the whole image tag inside , so that I can show the magnified image. Since I'm new to React, I'm very lost here to do that. Can anyone help me do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`e.target` hold all props you need:

```js
handleClickOpen = e => {
  console.log(e.target.src)
}
```

Comment: Stunning! Thanks!

Comment: By the way, after getting the `src`, passing it to `<Dialog/>` through `state` is most conventional?